# 16x2 lcd display to raspberry pi black text instead of white

Tags: lcd, 16x2

I just connected a lcd 16x2 display to the raspberry pi (directly, no breadboard). I can display text and send command to it without problem.
The only problem is that the text is black while it should be white (blue backlight).
Any thought on how I could fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We need much more info to begin to answer your question. We will need to see clear photos of all connections and the part itself. Having said that have you connected the backlight?

Comment: Is your lcd color or blue and white?

Comment: how do you know that the text should be white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a resistor and plug it to the 5V pin. Now it displays white on blue, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Those HD44780 driven LCDs don't have reverse characters in their character set. If yours is displaying black text on the background, you are stuck with that.

— Well, you could undo the display frame and flip the polarizer, but most times, it's glued onto the glass. It's up to you if you find it worth a try. —

You end up with blue text on black then, of course. Cool? Not cool?

The "white text on blue" variant has a special blueish polarizer instead of a black one and a white backlight.